# Looking for blond hair girl with pink dragon tail anime

Tags: lotte-no-omocha

I only know very little about the anime but I would like to finish it.

Here's what I know:

- The main character is a little girl with long blonde hair and she has a pink dragon tail with a heart on the end.
- Their is also a guy with blue or black hair who has a daughter, and they are both from the human world.
- And I think the only way to get to the magical world is through a tree in the middle of a lake.

And that is really all I know and I would love for someone to help me identify this anime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're talking about Astarotte Ygvar:

[image: Astarotte Ygvar]

---

## [Astarotte no Omocha!](http://myanimelist.net/anime/9736/Astarotte_no_Omocha!)

[image: cover]

## Synopsis

> While job hunting, Naoya is taken by a mysterious girl to a magical land where he is installed in the harem of the succubus Princess Lotte. Thanks to trauma from her childhood, Lotte hates men and surrounds herself with lots of other women, who all have quirks of their own. In spite of her selfishness, when Naoya learns that Lotte is really quite lonely he agrees to stay in her world ...if he can bring his daughter Asuha with him.

Source: ANN

Comment: Aw no comments on the first image >_<

Comment: I had to quickly swipe my screen downwards since I'm at work <.<

Comment: ^ maybe you should post first picture as NSFW, or just change it

Comment: @ShinobuOshino how is that not safe for work? I mean if it was some porn etc I would agree but its merely a drawing.

Comment: @Prix some may think of it as NSFW because of the panty shot. i have no problem with it personally, neither does my work, otherwise the calendar image of Sara kissing Kaede in Sono Hanabira 2: My Dear Prince would be taken down cause you see more of Sara's panties in that than you do in the image you've posted

Comment: Well since I can't judge it myself(as here is not considered NSFW), if this comment gets 4 or more votes or a moderator believes it needs to be censored I will add the spoiler into it.

Comment: I don't see it as NSFW tho, I just make a comment based on Krikara's comment